# How can I select items from date interval regardless of years — Informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

I have trouble with selecting items from a particular date interval.
I want to select items from an interval based only on days and month.

**items_table**

```
 item_name  | date_from
item1         30.6.2015
item2         31.7.2015
item3         5.8.2019
item4         14.8.2000
```

I need something like this:

```
select * 
from items_table 
where date_from
between '****-07-31' and '****-08-13';
```

**** can be everything - for example 2010, 2011, 2012....

I would like to get only:

```
item2
item3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date parts with some arithmetic:

```
where month(date_from) * 100 + day(date_from) between 0731 and 0813
```

Or as strings:

```
where to_char(date_from, '%m-%d') between '0731' and '0813'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
select * 
from items_table 
where
extend(date_from, month to day) between extend('2000-07-31'::date, month to day) and extend('1998-08-13'::date, month to day);
```

years 2000 and 1998 are irrelevant as they will be zeroed when comparison is performed.